# Firebase onWrite not triggered

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I read all the answers I found about this but I still have some problems. Probably something with .ref(), but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. My cloud function is not triggered at all.

DB example: 
business/{businessId}/reservations/{reservationId}

I want to trigger this function every time when a new reservation is created [a new document is created in reservation collection] (business/{businessId}/reservations/). 
And then I want to sent a notification message, but that is another thing.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

    exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.database
      .ref("business/{businessId}/reservations")
      .onWrite((event: any) => {
       // It never comes here...
        console.log('Here');

        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'New registration',
            body: 'You have new registration!',
          },
        };

        // You can ignore this part
        admin
        .messaging()
        .sendToDevice('SomeToken', payload)
        .catch(function (error: any) {
          console.log('Notification sent failed:', error);
        });

      });
```

Comment: While that trigger doesn't do exactly what you described, I would still expect it to trigger every time a new node is created under reservations.  Maybe you would like to edit the question to explain exactly what you're doing that should trigger this?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the answer, I just updated the description. I hope now it's more clear what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're using the terms "document" and "collection" suggests that your database is Firestore.  But what you've written here is a Realtime Database trigger.  Realtime Database is a completely different database. Instead, you will need to write a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) instead.  They begin with `functions.firestore`.